# For which $f: \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}^+$ does the sum $\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} f(q)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, rational-numbers

**BACKGROUND:**

This is not a homework question -- I am not even in school. I am purely interested in the question itself. I actually asked this question in my second semester of real analysis during my math major, but that was years ago. The professor found the question interesting but was unable to provide a satisfying answer.

I know the sum $\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,\varepsilon)}q$ diverges to $\infty$ (since infinitely many terms are larger than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$). But $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, and so there must be some "sums over the rationals" which converge.

Of course we need to avoid the ambiguity of unordered infinite series with positive and negative terms (since rearrangement of terms does not preserve the sum). So I am only interested in sums of positive terms, i.e. $\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}f(q)$ where $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}^+$.

Intuitively, the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ makes convergence a lot harder to achieve for an arbitrary sum. We won't have success with something like $\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}}\frac{1}{q^2}$, since there will still be too many terms that are bigger than any $\varepsilon>0$, in this case for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}^{\neq0}\cap\big(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\big)$. This seems to suggest that functions that have a simple formula for $f(q)$, written in terms of $q$, will rarely (almost never?) have a convergent sum.

So to make my question a bit more specific and therefore easier to answer, I want to focus my question only on the following example.

**MY ACTUAL QUESTION:**

Any rational number can be uniquely described as a fraction in lowest terms. For which positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ does the following sum converge?

$$\sum_{\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}} \frac{1}{|m|^a+|n|^b}$$

Intuitively, if we use powers of $1$, then this fraction might--like the harmonic series--not shrink to zero quickly enough for the sum to converge. To further build intuition, I will informally define the "${l}^a$ complexity" of rational numbers to be $$\bigg|\frac{m}{n}\bigg|_a=\big(|m|^a+|n|^a\big)^{\frac{1}{a}}$$

To illustrate, $\big|\frac{-3}{4}\big|_2=(3^2+4^2)^\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{25}=5$, but $\big|\frac{-3}{4}\big|_1=(3^1+4^1)^\frac{1}{1}=7$. To avoid ambiguity, we will choose the canonical representation of $0$ to be the fraction $\frac{0}{1}$, so that $|0|_a=(0^a+1^a)^\frac{1}{a}=1$. Since $0=\frac{0}{1}$ is the rational number written with the smallest possible numerator and denominator, we see that $|q|_a \geq 1$ for any $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. In general, "more complicated" rational numbers will have larger $l^a$ complexity than "simpler" rational numbers: $\big|\frac{456}{1207}\big|_a>\big|\frac{1}{2}\big|_a$.

This leads to an even smaller and more restrictive question.

**A SIMPLER QUESTION THAT MIGHT HELP ME MAKE PROGRESS:**

For which $a>1$ does the following sum converge?

$$\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \frac{1}{|q|_a^a}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the last question: The answer is that it converges iff $a>2$. It is easy to check that your question is equivalent to asking for which $a >1$ the following sum converges:
$$
\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}  \atop\text{ relative prime }} \frac{1}{n^a+m^a}.
$$
The cruical step it to get rid of the "relative prime" here, i.e. show that
$$
\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}  } \frac{1}{n^a+m^a} < \infty \iff \sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}  \atop\text{ relative prime }} \frac{1}{n^a+m^a} < \infty 
$$
The direct implication is trivial because the left sum is bigger than the right. For the reverse implication assume the right sum to be finite and denote $\text{gcd}(m,n)$ the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$. Note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}  } \frac{1}{n^a+m^a} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}  \atop\text{gcd}(m,n)=k} \frac{1}{n^a+m^a} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}  \atop\text{ relative prime }} \frac{1}{(kn)^a+(km)^a}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^a} \sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}  \atop\text{ relative prime }} \frac{1}{n^a+m^a} < \infty.
\end{align}

Now, it is easy to check that $\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}  } \frac{1}{n^a+m^a} < \infty $, iff the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus B(0,1)} \frac{1}{||x||^a} dx
$$
is finite. ($B(0,1)$ denotes the unit ball). This is known to be true, iff $a>2$.

Comment: Wow, thanks!! Just to clarify, the convergence of the sum and the integral in your last step is because all pairs of naturals are at a minimum distance of 1 from the origin, and while $||x||^a$ is the $l^a$ norm, the definition of the norm for $B(0,1)$ doesn't actually matter, as long as it's a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the origin. Am I correct in saying the precise definition of the ball isn't necessary to the argument?

Comment: Also, you have shown that my question about rational numbers is (in terms of convergence) equivalent to a question about double sums.. the structure of the rational numbers might affect the values of these sums (n and m are coprime), but it doesn't affect whether these sums converge. I'd say that's a strong to 2/3 of my question, although the second part of my question might be harder.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote: "This seems to suggest that functions that have a simple formula for $f(q)$, written in terms of $q$, will rarely (almost never?) have a convergent sum."

This is in some sense true, because one can prove the following rigorous statement:

Let $f : \mathbb{Q} \to [0,\infty)$ be continuous s.t. $\sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} f(q)$ is convergent. Then $f=0$.

Proof: Assume that $f$ is not constant zero. Then exitsis $q_0$ s.t. $f(q_0)>0$. By continuity there is some $\epsilon>0$ s.t. for all $q \in (q_0-\epsilon,q_0+\epsilon)$ we have $f(q)>f(q_0)/2$. Since $(q_0-\epsilon,q_0+\epsilon)$ contains infintely many elements, that implies that the sum diverges.

Remark: Clearly, there are discontinuous non-zero functions $f : \mathbb{Q} \to [0,\infty)$ s.t. $\sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} f(q)$ converges. For example: Let $\Phi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ a bijection. Let $f(q):= 2^{-\Phi^{-1}(q)}$, then  $\sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} f(q) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}2^{-n}=1$.

Comment: Nice! Right, the existence of that bijection is why I know that convergent sums exist. But of course there are very many such bijections, and I don't want to use my choice of $\mathbb{\Phi}$ when looking for convergent sums. Your example clearly works, but I'm still wondering about my function as well as the general question of _which_ functions have convergent sums.

Comment: Your informal argument was: "intuitively, the density of Q makes convergence a lot harder". This indicates that you should use that topological property of Q in the argument, which indicates that you should look a continuous functions to make a rigorous statement. Clearly, my argument works if I replace "continuous" by "continuous on a nbhd of some $x$ s.t. $f(x)>0$. One can observe that all finite compositions of algebraic operations satisfy this (when involving $1/x$ and doing some casedistinction on $x=0$ it still satisfies my weaker condition introduced in this comment)

Comment: This statement then has more the flavour of "evering I can write down easily fails". The problem is: You can also "write down easily" some $f$ that is non-zero at finitely many points, which is then an example without using the bijection. I don't think that you will be able to get a nice "iff"-statement for the convergence, because even for series indexed with $\mathbb{N}$ there is not one necessary and sufficient criterion for convergence of a sum (expect for trivial reformulations of the definition of convergence), but there a lots of useful necessary OR sufficent conditions.

Comment: Yes, you have certainly made a meaningful contribution and I'm not intending to downplay that. However, if you read again, my actual question (labeled with bold font) is the sum of the reciprocal of the powers of the numerator and denominator, and specifically which powers (a, b) cause that sum to converge? Is it whenever either a or b is greater than 1? Is it when they multiply to be at least 2?

Comment: Your answer is an excellent response to the "background" part of my question. Just not to my question itself.

Comment: Also, caution: Just because continuous functions greater than 0 won't work, that does NOT imply that it can only have finite support. There can be infinitely many nonzero points, scattered in a discontinuous way, as in the example provided in my question.